# What does "going into turn two" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *[F9 (2021)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F9_(film))*, Racer stops in middle of the car racing track:

> Racer: Tell me what you see, Dom.
>
> Dom: Got an oil spill **going into turn two**. Bell's driving safe.
> Corbin's got a sponsor in the stands, so he's pushing it.

What does "going into turn two" mean?

Comment: The racing track has a number of turns or corners, generally counting from the starting grid. So the first turn is **turn one** and the second turn is **turn two**. Most tracks give their turns/corners specific names as well, which fans get to know. Commentators will use these names when describing the progress of the race.

Comment: Hey Elena, and welcome to ELL Stack Exchange! [Good questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) here have certain features, including doing your own research first. We do not provide definitions of words that you can find in a simple search. If you've already tried to look up "go into", please tell us what you found and why you're still unsure of the correct answer. :)